# Maths in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, math

im trying to do a simple sum in php using entryies in my database by displaying them in the file. all other fields show perfectly apart from the sum

```
    <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT make, id, model, bcosts, rcosts, value, id FROM referb';

mysql_select_db('ely');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
    echo "<tbody><tr class=\"odd\">

        <td>{$row['make']} </td>".
         "<td>{$row['model']} </td> ".
         "<td>{$row['id']}</td> ".
         "<td>{$row['bcosts']}</td> ".
         "<td>{$row['value']}</td> ".
         "<td>{$row['rcosts']}</td> ".
         "<td> £ 

$first_number = {$row['bcosts']};
 $second_number = {$row['rcosts']};
 $third_number = {$row['value']};

$sum_total = $third_number - $second_number - $first_number;

print ($sum_total);


 </td> ";
} 

?>
```

the out put i get for this is

```
£ = 100; = 25; = 300; = - - ; print ();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the string you are printing:

```
"<td> £ 

$first_number = {$row['bcosts']};
$second_number = {$row['rcosts']};
$third_number = {$row['value']};

$sum_total = $third_number - $second_number - $first_number;

print ($sum_total);


</td> ";
```

The variables get replaced with their values:

```
"<td> £ 

 = 100;
 = 25;
 = 300;

 =  -  - ;

print ();


</td> ";
```

And the browser converts multiple whitespace characters into one space when displaying.

You cannot calculate stuff during inside the string. This should fix it:

```
"<td> £"; 

$first_number = $row['bcosts'];
$second_number = $row['rcosts'];
$third_number = $row['value'];

$sum_total = $third_number - $second_number - $first_number;

print ($sum_total);


echo "</td> ";
```